# JSF: use <f:setPropertyActionListener /> inside a graphicImage

Tags: java, jsf

Every time I try to use "setPropertyActionListener" inside an graphicImage, this shows up:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN1I3.png)

```html
<h:graphicImage value="/images/h.png">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pokemonController.haarfarbe}" value="h" />
</h:graphicImage>
```

Does it only work with commandButtons?

**EDIT:**
correct way:

```html
<h:commandLink action="Augenfarbe.xhtml">
      <h:graphicImage value="/images/h.png" />             
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pokemonController.hautfarbe}" value="h" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite true, the image ui element in JSF is only a box for a graphic.
The JSF ui component must implement ActionSource interface in its hierarchy to bind an event.
Also, command button elements do not tend to operate unless inside a jsf form element.
You can wrap a commandButton around the image.